# executing jquery function after a global object resolved

Tags: javascript, jquery, promise

In my page I have following scripts that will be loaded:

```
<script src="~/js/dir/search.js"></script>
<script src="~/js/dir/item.js"></script>
```

Inside `search.js` file I use ES6 inside global scope:

```
fetch(endpoint)
    .then(blob => blob.json())
    .then(data => members.push(...data));
```

And inside `item.js` I use this script to show `members` object:

```
$(window).load(() => {
   console.log(members);
});
```

But it prints `undefined` in the console, How do I ensure that if `search.js` completely loads then `items.js` give the result?

Comment: Note that `search.js` loads and executes, before `item.js` does. But I guess your `fetch()` is async and doesn't finish in time.

Comment: @FabianKlötzl Yes, What do you think, any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could expose an API from one file to register an extra handler in the other.

search.js:

```
var p = fetch(endpoint);
p.then(…);
window.extraHandler = function (fn){
    p.then(fn);
}
```

item.js:

```
extraHandler(function(){
    console.log(members);
});
```